# Find non.numerical arguent in a table from csv

Tags: r

I face this problem:
I prepared a data table in excel and then export as a CSV to R.
I used the function `read.csv2`. After I set the data frame, I am trying to exclude the first column with the name of the `country`.

I would like to plot and do the PC analysis, but I'm stuck on the non-numerical argument problem.
How can I handle it or find a possible non-numerical factor?
The error is:

```
> pairs(dati)
> Error in pairs.default(dati) : non-numeric argument to 'pairs'
```

Update:

```
> str(dati)
'data.frame':   184 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Political Stability and Absence of Violence/Terrorism: chr  "1.17" "-2.41" "-2.06" "-0.33" ...
 $ Government Effectiveness                             : chr  "1.41" "-2.18" "-0.86" "-0.69" ...
 $ Voice and Accountability                             : chr  "1.56" "-1.91" "-1.58" "-0.65" ...
 $ Rule of Law                                          : chr  "1.16" "-1.79" "-1.63" "-0.68" ...
 $ Regulatory Quality                                   : chr  "1.27" "-2.09" "-1.42" "-0.47" ...
 $ Control of Corruption                                : chr  "1.32" "-1.29" "-1.17" "-0.89" ...
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `str(dati)` in your question? You probably have a numeric vector coded as character or factor.

Comment: Try `dati2 <- type.convert(dati, as.is = TRUE)`

Comment: thank you so much, basically what did you do?

Comment: Based on the output you posted, you have a bunch of numeric columns coded as character. `type.convert` tries to intelligently convert columns to their respective types, in this case numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pairs` is failing because your data frame only has character columns.

We can try fixing this using `type.convert()` which will convert all the character columns to the appropriate class.

```
dati2 <- type.convert(dati, as.is = TRUE)

pairs(dati2)
```